# Load image asset at runtime with Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am loading a PNG image from the asset folder like so:

```
string texture = "Assets/Sprites/Maps/Map1.png";
Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(texture, typeof(Texture2D));
```

This works fine, but upon building the game it doesn't work. I guess it's because this is a debug/editor specific function that the Unity Player can't handle.

My question:
Is there another way to load image assets that works with the compiled game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asset folder no longer exists after you built. You need to store your asset in Resources or StreamingAssets folders.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Comment: Hi, I will try it. Are these types of assets and resources compressed like regular assets? EDIT: Okay, StreamingAssets are not.

Comment: The Resource folder should not be used described in [this](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/resources-folder) article

Comment: What do you mean should not be used? The article actually explains how to use it.